# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android

A script on my server returns an array of SQL rows. An appropriate curl returns string which is correct:

```
[{"ID":"1","DATETIME":"2021-05-30 21:29:27","SETPOINT":"45.22","LUMIN":"65.98","DIRECTION":"LOG"},{"ID":"1","DATETIME":"2021-05-30 15:55:34","REVS":"2.11934","ROTATION":"1","DIRECTION":"LOG","POSITION":"12"}]
```

However, while parsing it in my Android application, I am getting an error `org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`. Closer investigation (`Toast` printing) to what is passed indicated that the application is receiving the remote script's address `http://<ip>/readLatest.php`, and not the array, as seen with the curl query.

What seems to be a problem? Other answers as to similar questions were not helpful

**Async task:**

```java
public class DataGetter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    Context context;
    private GetListener GetListener;
    public String jsonString;
    public boolean passed_successfully;

    DataGetter(Context ctx, GetListener listener) {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.GetListener = listener;
        this.passed_successfully = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        String ip = params[0];
        String scriptname = params[1];
        String db = params[2];
        String urladress = "http://" + ip + "/"+ scriptname +".php";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urladress);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("database", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(db, "UTF-8");

            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            connection.disconnect();

            return new String[] {sb.toString(), scriptname};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String[] {e.getMessage()};
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String... result) {
        GetListener.passJSONGet(result);
    }
}
```

**Part of appropriate Activity:**

```java
@Override
    public void passJSONGet(String... result) {
        String jsonstring = result[0];
        try {
            showToast(jsonstring);
            this.jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonstring);
            this.printControls(jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void printControls(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        String lumin = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1).getString("LUMIN");
        this.luminval.setText(String.format("%s", lumin));
        int position = Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("POSITION"));
        this.positionval.setText(String.format("%s", position));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, where are you executing your async task? Also, what are the parameters being passed into it?

Comment: @CodingChap I'm executing the AsyncTask in `onCreate` method of the activity with this parameters `this.dataGetterBlinds.execute(ip, "readLatestBlinds", "intel_blinds");`